# What do I need to do to finish retagging "datacontractjsonserialize" as "datacontractjsonserializer"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Now that the 25 character limit for tags has been [raised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/344280), I'd like to retag [datacontractjsonserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datacontractjsonserialize) as [datacontractjsonserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datacontractjsonserializer).  (Notice the added `r` on the end of the new tag?  The previous tag truncated the last character of the class name [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) to fit into the old character length limit.)

I've gone and created the new tag and retagged the pre-existing questions.  Is there anything else I need to do?  It seems I can't suggest `datacontractjsonserialize` as a synonym for `datacontractjsonserializer` despite having 11 votes in the previous tag.

Comment: If the tag has no questions, it will be deleted. So nothing to do

Comment: wouldn't it  been easier if a mod did a rename?

Comment: Does every knock and cranny needs its own tag? Really? The class is barely 4 pages long, with very wide margins.

Comment: @rene - maybe?  Was this the wrong way to go about doing this?

Comment: @dbc I don't mind, some users get annoyed if their active list is spoiled with tag-edits only and it takes time and effort out of your day while it can be an easy, no sweat action from a mod. Given they have their flag queue under control now I guess they have no issue handling such requests in a timely manner. But your approach works, sure.

Comment: As @rene alludes, I'm one of those people who get annoyed by community-initiated mass-retags. Conveniently, I am now *also* one of those people who can do a moderator-initiated rename. :-) So, please feel free to ping me or raise a custom moderator flag when you want something like this. The only time we ever need to do a grassroots project is when we're doing a *cleanup* and you are making other edits to the questions while you're modifying the tags. That can still be very disruptive, and should preferably be staggered out, but it does offer benefits that can outweigh its disadvantages.

Comment: In the future, where I say *some users* please read *Cody Gray* ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing else that needs to be done. The old tag with 0 questions will automatically disappear when the tag cleanup process runs. There's no need to create a synonym for a misspelled tag. No one is gonna be wondering where their tag missing an R went.