# Should the [htm] tag be truncated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I see there's a few questions tagged with [htm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htm), which all seem to be about HTML. Perhaps folks are using [htm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htm) because of the common `.htm` file extension?

Should the tag be nuked and merged into [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)?

Comment: Or maybe people just aren't paying much attention and click [tag:htm] since it comes up before [tag:html] in the tags list when tagging a question. In fact, I bet that the tag was accidentally created by someone with enough rep who meant to type `html` in the tag bar and missed the `l`.

Comment: OK, no more `htm` questions are there. Could a mod with tag deletion rights can do the honors?

Comment: [The old tag with 0 questions will automatically disappear when the tag cleanup process runs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354820/7795130)